# Detecting numbers in natural language in iOS, e.g. "1/2" -> 0.5, "thirty-three" -> 33, "dozen" -> 12

Tags: ios, cocoa, nlp

I've tried [NSLinguisticTagger](http://nshipster.com/nslinguistictagger/), which is great to a point, and tags examples such as:

```
"1" // assigns Number tag
"one" // assigns Number tag
"thirty" // assigns Number tag
```

but breaks down for examples such as:

```
"1/2" // assigns Number,Punctuation,Number tags
"0.5" // assigns OtherWord tag
"½" [unicode half] // assigns OtherWord tag
"half" // assigns Adverb tag (this one is technically accurate)
"ninety-nine" // assigns Number,Number or Number,Dash,Number depending on options
"dozen" // assigns OtherWord
```

Is there a way of either:

- Extending/improving NSLinguisticTagger to obtain the desired behaviour
- Using an alternative method/API/library that's compatible with iOS?

Or should I just go back to heuristics, e.g. try to coerce tokens to floats (should catch `0.5`) and just create a dictionary of other possibilities (e.g. `half`, `quarter`, `eighth`, etc.) to search through, and then look for the pattern `Number,Punctuation,Number` for fractions.

Either way, I would like to extract these numbers as floats somehow! If there's not a good way of doing this in iOS, knowing where to start with e.g. Python/NLTK would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use Illinois-quantities package: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/quantities/index.php

Comment: Thanks; that's exactly what I was looking for, but doesn't seem well-suited to iOS. Its license is restrictive and it's written in Java, which is not supported in iOS. Do you know of any publications that explain how that was made? It doesn't seem like the Illinois Cognitive Computation Group have published this work yet.

Comment: Typically, these approaches use a large set of regular expressions. There are only so many words used to describe numbers. You may also look at [heideltime](https://code.google.com/p/heideltime/) (except it is also Java).

Comment: @mayhewsw thanks for the link; there are some useful publications on that page to get started with. I'm not sure they are just using regular expressions though, it looks like it's in conjunction with a parts-of-speech tagger.